# Can you add custom T4 Templates to the VS2008 "Add New Item" dialog?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, t4

I have created a set of templates that I want to share across multiple projects. Is it possible to add the template to the Project “Add New Item” dialog such that when I choose it an instance of the code file is generated from the template and added to the project?

#### Update

Thanks for suggestions Preet. That answers the question but I think I have asked the wrong one. Thinking about it some more, I now want to be able automate the processing of T4 templates and pass parameters to them from user input.

I'm now looking at this from a new angle. Specifically attempting to use the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.Engine` class and GAX to generate code files from templates myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't see why not - you just create an Item template. See [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2F6db0hwky(VS.80).aspx&ei=dZfMSaraDYmGsQOz_ZWwCg&usg=AFQjCNELGM7uocuw323fxmejmFNroMwNgA&sig2=iC4obPrlGwOJdq72koZTNQ) and [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=6&url=http%3A%2F%2Fvisualstudiomagazine.com%2Fcolumns%2Farticle.aspx%3Feditorialsid%3D2761&ei=dZfMSaraDYmGsQOz_ZWwCg&usg=AFQjCNEJ1zV4zIeeBFnWf1jUuYAljfT5zw&sig2=UKs_iEFlpV1ilXNjd9gN2w) for more details